# Laravel Multiple table query for three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, laravel-5

I am very new in laravel, I have created a query which is perfectly working in Xampp server, Now i want convert this query in laravel, I created one laravel code which is showing error `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'question_chapter_rel' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from`question_chapter_rel`inner join`question_chapter_rel`on`chapters`.`id`=`question_chapter_rel`.`chapter_id`inner join`questions`on`questions`.`id`=`question_chapter_rel`.`question_id`inner join`answers`on`answers`.`id`=`questions`.`correct_answers`where`answers`.`is_correct`= 1)`

This is my laravel query:

```
public function scopeGetQuestion($query)
    {

       return $query->join('question_chapter_rel', 'chapters.id', '=' ,'question_chapter_rel.chapter_id')
                    ->join('questions','questions.id', '=' ,'question_chapter_rel.question_id')
                    ->join('answers','answers.id', '=' ,'questions.correct_answers')
            ->select(
                [
                    'chapters.id',
                    'chapters.chapter_description',
                    'questions.id',
                    'questions.question_description',
                    'answers.id',
                    'answers.answer_description'
                ]
            )

            ->where('answers.is_correct',1)
            ->paginate(12);
    }
```

This is the code I want to convert

```
select `chapters`.`id`, `chapters`.`chapter_description`, `questions`.`id`, `questions`.`question_description`, `answers`.`id`, `answers`.`answer_description`

from `chapters`
Inner Join `question_chapter_rel`
on `chapters`.`id` = `question_chapter_rel`.`chapter_id`

Inner Join `questions`
on `questions`.`id` = `question_chapter_rel`.`question_id`

Inner Join `answers`
on `answers`.`id` = `questions`.`correct_answers`

where `answers`.`is_correct` = 1
```

Thanks in advance

question_chapter_rel Table  [image: question_chapter_rel Table] chapter Table [image: chapter Table]  question Table [image: question Table]  answers Table  [image: answers Table]

Answer (score 0):

Always you can use DB::raw. Check join statement in laracast docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#joins

check this

pls add use DB;

```
public function scopeGetQuestion($query)
{
    dd(DB::table('chapters')->select('chapters.id', 'chapters.chapter_description', 'questions.id', 'questions.question_description', 'answers.id', 'answers.answer_description')->join('question_chapter_rel', 'chapters.id', '=' ,'question_chapter_rel.chapter_id')->join('questions','questions.id', '=' ,'question_chapter_rel.question_id')->join('answers','answers.id', '=' ,'questions.correct_answers')->where('answers.is_correct', '=' ,1)->get());
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your resource But its not working at all, data is not showing from database.

Comment: Respone change, code modify. Check this and can u show table srtucture with data?

Comment: Hello, I have changed my question added table description with data and details of error.

Comment: Thanks I got the solution

Comment: code update // move chapters table from joins clasue to from in db query

Answer (score 0):

```
This how its works, From the first line use **chapter** instead **question_chapter_rel**


  public function scopeGetQuestion($query,$id)
        {

            return $query->join('chapters', 'chapters.id', '=' ,'question_chapter_rel.chapter_id')
                ->join('questions','questions.id', '=' ,'question_chapter_rel.question_id')
                ->join('answers','answers.id', '=' ,'questions.correct_answers')
                ->where('answers.is_correct',1)
                ->where('question_chapter_rel.chapter_id',$id)
                ->select(
                    [

                        'chapters.id',
                        'chapters.chapter_description',
                        'questions.id',
                        'questions.question_description',
                        'answers.id',
                        'answers.answer_description'
                    ]
                )


            ->paginate(20);
        }
```